# Programmatically refresh screenshot in iOS7 multitasking screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, multitasking

I have a music player app which implements background audio. I’m trying to update the screenshot in the iOS7 multi-tasking switcher when the track changes. So, if I background the app during Song A, it finishes and Song B comes on, if I then go into the tray I’d like to see a screenshot showing Song B’s artwork, title, etc.

I’ve done some digging and not managed to find any way to tell iOS to update short of implementing Background Fetch and going all out with that. Is there another means of doing this, something I can call to tell it to refresh it when my tracks change?

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not provide any means of doing this. Even iOS own media player does not have this ability.

Comment: There’s definitely a means of doing it. Check Session 204 from WWDC, “Updating snapshots in the background”.

Comment: It is on the slide of the 204 session, but no where in the documentation is this mentioned. [Multitasking Enhancements](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW10) has not mentiom of this nor does [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4). Either it's an mistake on the slide or snapshot != screenshot.

Comment: So, you can update it by implementing `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler`, and telling the `completionHandler` that you have new data. This’ll cause it to refresh, and get a new snapshot. Not sure whether this’d constitute misuse of the API, though?

Comment: Nowhere in the [`application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW46) is it state the the snapshot will be updated. Also you can not call this method your self, only the system can.

Comment: Right, but I can tell the system how often to call it. If my first track is 3:20, and I set its minimum refresh to 200, it won’t call it again during that 3:20. I’d then update the minimum upon each new track starting. It won’t be perfect, but it’s better than nothing. I’m just wondering whether it’s grounds for app rejection in that state.

Comment: Session 204:

"And then after you've done all of that and you've gotten that brand new stuff, you're going to call the completion handler that was called that was passed in and that's really important.

That's where your snapshot gets taken and will go right into that app switcher UI, so that if the user is passing by your application the app switcher, they can see, "Hey, look, there's brand new content there."

Comment: Yes you can set the fetch interval, but it is up to the system if it is going to call it. It will look at how often the app is tarted by the user and will then schedule a background fetch for your app. So there is not way you have 100% control over it. Also since you app is already running in background my guess is that it will not be marked for background fetch.

Comment: Seems to be working here, albeit shakily. May be doable, though. Any thoughts on whether Apple wouldn’t like it?

Comment: This is one you will have to discover, just be aware that is you users have turned of background fetching or the OS think you are updating to much, it will not work. So I give your solution 50% chance of working.

Comment: Also, if you’re interested, there’s quite a bit more information on updating the snapshot in one of the iOS7 Tech Talk videos (Integrating iOS7 Technologies)